# ubuntu 14.04 LTS webpack --watch not recompiling after a few times

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, webpack, jsx

I'm using Webpack along with Babel to compile my jsx into js. --watch will work a few times but then stop afterwards. I've had to resort to manually typing in webpack every time in order to make sure my scripts get compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this where it turned out that webpack was silently failing to report that I had exceeded the max number of **inotify watchers** in Linux. Webpack *watch* uses inotify to observe file changes.

You can immediately try a fix to see if it works with:

```
sudo -i
echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
exit
```

The long term fix would be to increase your allowed watchers by editing your `/etc/sysctl.conf` to include this line: `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576`.

The issue was reported here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1281